# Get Field value from object using string key

Tags: apex, lightning, sobject

I am trying to do get values from the object using string key, I have typecast the Contact object into the object but not getting value. Please help how to get value from the object using string API filed

```
List<String> lstfiedName = new List<String>{'LastName','Email','Phone'};     
for(Contact objContact : lstofContact){
 object obj = (object)objContact;
  for(String fielName : lstfiedName){
      System.debug('lastname::'+obj.get(fiedName));
  }
}
```

Getting Error : 
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type Object

Answer (score 5):

try with sObject instead of Contact since get and set methods are available in sObject class. Replace your `Contact objContact` with `sObject objContact` in for loop. Also, try without `Object obj` as it should work fine without casting it to Object type